# Filtering Server Response RestKit + CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, restkit

Im using RestKit+CoreData. And i always get response code 200 from server. And I don't need all responses to save into core data, Is there any way to filter response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the addFetchRequestBlock to give a fetch request with predicate, by which you can avoid saving unwanted objects from responses.

Reference : 
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RestKit/0.24.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html